# Nested Select statement - Getting datasets with strings between two string values

Tags: sql, select, sqlite, nested

I am currently trying to fetch entries from a database with a certain range. The strings found in the table are dates in the format `yyyyMMdd`. Edit: stored as strings; not as dates!

The table looks like this (without ID):

```
+----------+----------+----------+
|    c1    |    c2    |    c3    |
+----------+----------+----------+
| 20161101 | 20161102 | 20161027 |
| 20131212 | 20161102 | 20161028 |
+----------+----------+----------+
```

With the following code I can get the smallest "value" over the three columns for each row:

```
SELECT MIN(c1, c2, c3) FROM my_table WHERE c1 IS NOT NULL AND c2 IS NOT NULL AND c3 IS NOT NULL;

+-----------------+
| MIN(c1, c2, c3) |
+-----------------+
|        20161027 |
|        20131212 |
+-----------------+
```

However when I try to use it as part of a nested SQL-Query to get only the ones that are e.g. made between 2015 and 2017 (excluding the second row) with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE MIN(c1, c2, c3) IN (SELECT MIN(c1, c2, c3) FROM my_table WHERE c1 IS NOT NULL AND c2 IS NOT NULL AND c3 IS NOT NULL) BETWEEN '2015' AND '2017';
```

I do not get any results at all. I tested other things as well like `... LIKE '2016%'` (not producing any results) and `... LIKE '%'` Giving all results shown above in the table.

What I want to get out would be

```
+----------+----------+----------+
|    c1    |    c2    |    c3    |
+----------+----------+----------+
| 20161101 | 20161102 | 20161027 |
+----------+----------+----------+
```

I assume that I am working incorrectly with the nested SELECT-statement, but after 2 hours of searching and testing I cannot figure out what is wrong.

I am using SQLite Studio 3.1.0 to test the queries and a local sqlite 3 database to execute the queries on.

Any help is much appreciated! If I should add more possible inputs/outputs, tell me so I can do so.

Comment: What does the min of the 3 columns have to do with the date range?

Comment: I have to get the smallest one of them because it is a certain value that I have to look on. To be more specific it specifies when this set is generated; this however can be done by different persons, setting the value in different columns. I did not want to make an extra column just for that as then one value would be twice in each row. It is not exactly necessary for this problem, but I included it to make sure the problem is shown in its total and not just small bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic appears to be that you want to retain records where the minimum date of (`c1`, `c2`, and `c3`) is between 2015 and 2017.  If so, then the following should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE STRFTIME('%Y-%m-%d', MIN(c1, c2, c3)) BETWEEN DATE('2015-01-01') AND DATE('2017-12-31')
```

Further you should change the format to `YYYY-mm-dd`.

Comment: I think you misunderstood a little... I want to get all rows with their minimum value beeing beetween 2015 and 2017 (whereas this value is supposed to be more specific and variable in the future). It is also possible that a row is generated on the last of 2017 and in another column a value gets added starting with 2018. This row should then still be caught by the query.

Comment: What happens if one or more value be `NULL`?  Is the record ignored entirely, or only that particular NULL column?

Comment: They should be caught. After testing however it seems that null-values are always taken as minimum so I placed the `IS NOT NULL` construct there. I will work on that as well but it currently makes no difference.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question.  If a record had `NULL` for all 3 columns, would you logically treat that as a match or not a match?

Comment: There wont be a record holding 3 `NULL` values. This whole thing will be part of a program that will take care of that.

Comment: Then my query should work for you.  I believe `MIN` will ignore `NULL` values, and since you just said that at least one column will be non-NULL, then there is no issue here.

Comment: Ok I just saw your edit. The whole thing will be set up to work with a java project where you can set the environment where the first entry was supposed to be made. If I understand your edit correctly I can adjust the frame changing the value in the `date()` commands. However my values are stored as strings. I tested it and I still get no results.

Comment: Now this is interesting. With the additional cast and the `between` I get an error: `Error while executing SQL query on database 'myDB': Result set expired or no row available.` Whereas when I comment out the restriction I get lines where no row contains a `NULL` .

Comment: I think I understand what you are doing. For that it should be `STRFTIME('%Y-%m-%d ... ` or am I wrong?

Comment: Your dates appear to have the format `20161101`, unless you gave us misinformation in the original question.

Comment: Correct but doesn't it work like input as yyyymmdd and output as yyyy-mm-dd? And I thought I would compare it to yyyy-mm-dd. Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Oh well... After giving out myself the result of `strftime()` it seems there is the problem... I get this output for the first line: `5048-39-17` Which is supposed to be the minimum of that line and formated to fit yyyy-mm-dd .

Any idea why that happens?

Comment: Then maybe your data has some problems.

Comment: What problems? I have never delt with such problems and have no idea what could be broken... The data is the one you see in the question above...

Comment: Is there any chance you have some whitespace in the `c` columns?

Comment: Quickly checked... No. I have found the problem however. A format like mine is actually interpreted as all days. -> 20161028 days I think I will then work with the format yyyy-mm-dd as this seems to work properly. Thanks a lot for your patience and suggestions!